# tailwindcss: Force tailwind to use compatible rgb syntax?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, tailwind-css

I'm porting an app using tailwindcss to work with IE11. Unfortunately, tailwindcss insists on generating colors using the modern [W3C CSS Color Module Level 4 rgb()](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#funcdef-rgb) syntax, which does not appear to be working in IE, e.g. it generates classes like these:

```css
.bg-blue-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(59 130 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

I have tried using [postcss-color-rgb](https://github.com/dmarchena/postcss-color-rgb) in my postcss pipeline to transform this back into the usual syntax to no avail:

```js
postcss([
    require('tailwindcss')(twConfig),
    require('postcss-color-rgb'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]).process(cssContent, {
    from: css,
    to: `build/${name}.css.tmp`
})
```

Tailwind claims to be compatible with any modern browser, which some might dare to classify IE11 as. Any thoughts on getting tailwind to play nicely with IE11 here?

Comment: The documentation clearly states it doesn't support IE 11: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support.

Comment: I agree with @firstlast mentioned. In addition, IE will also stop supporting in June this year. Using a modern browser like Chrome or Microsoft Edge would be a better choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tailwind will use this syntax when the [background opacity utilities](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity) are enabled.

If you disable it, it will use the regular hex syntax for colors, so you don't even need the `postcss-color-rgb` post css plugin anymore!

You can disable this by adding this to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      // ...

     backgroundOpacity: false,
    }
  }
```

In my case, I had a similar issue with text and border colors. You might need to experiment and figure out which of these "opacity" utilities are causing you trouble. For my project, I disabled all of them:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      // ...
        backdropOpacity: false,
        backgroundOpacity: false,
        borderOpacity: false,
        divideOpacity: false,
        ringOpacity: false,
        textOpacity: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is just a workaround, Actual question is how to transform the RGB format to RGBA