# Tailwind: opacity in color class breaks styling in :visited pseudo selector

Tags: css, cross-browser, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a project with Tailwind and I am trying to set the styles for a `:visited` element like this:
`class="visited:text-red"`
That works in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari it does not apply the style. After some debugging and reading docs I have found out that this happens because of the restrictions that are set for the `:visited` pseudo-class, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#privacy_restrictions and the fact that Tailwind creates my `text-red` class with

```
--tw-text-opacity: 1;
color: rgba(176, 190, 197, var(--tw-text-opacity));
```

thus applying an opacity indirectly which Chrome/Safari considers to be not allowed even if the link without any special state in fact already has opacity 1.
If the generated class had only

```
color: rgba(176, 190, 197);
```

it would work without any problems.
How can I fix this without creating my own utility color classes from scratch without the opacity? Are there any config options to prevent Tailwind from applying the opacity? Thankful for any suggestions / plugins etc.

Edit:
I know that I can work around it with the answer provided in [tailwindcss: Force tailwind to use compatible rgb syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754961/tailwindcss-force-tailwind-to-use-compatible-rgb-syntax). Nevertheless it would be cool if instead it would be possible to instruct Tailwind to create rgba values without the fourth value, instead

Comment: Could you show us how you are setting the non visited color?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I fix this without creating my own utility color classes from scratch without the opacity?

### Method 1

You can customize your color palette by editing `theme.colors` or `theme.extend.colors` in your `tailwind.config.js file` like below.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'regalBlue': '#243c5a',
      },
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like this `text-regalBlue`.

### Method 2

Ypu can simply use any color like this also `text-[#123123]`

Comment: That does not solve my problem, it's about the `:visited` and Tailwind adding an opacity value, I have added a detail to my question in order to make it clearer what my problem is here